# Path tracing of coordinates

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways cam we reach from the point $(0,0,0)$ to  point $(3,7,11)$ in space where the movement is possible only along the x-axis or z-axis or parallel to them and change of axes is permitted only at integral points? An integral point is a point whose coordinates are integers.

Sorry for not taking an approach as I am unable to understand how y-coordinate is changing when movement is not possible along y axis.

Comment: This problem is still open and NP-hard

Comment: Sure! You can't solve this problem only through simulations and trial and error, but first I need to know something. Can the mover intersect his own path traced before?

Comment: No he cannot intersect his own path.

Comment: Suddenly I studied a nice article from Wikipedia some weeks ago and worked on this problem some little. I'm gonna subscribe it within a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk

Here you can find some descriptions of what you want.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness

and you can discover the definition of NP-hardness. Also you can proceed further for other classes of problems such as P or NP class problems. Hope they help!

Comment: I will surely go through them thanx sir.